# log4j.xml show com.foo, but hide com.foo.bar

Tags: log4j, appender

I have the following log4j.xml configuration:

```
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name = "CONSOLE" class = "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name = "Target" value = "System.out"/>
        <param name = "Threshold" value = "DEBUG"/>
    </appender>
    <category name = "com.foo">
        <appender-ref ref = "CONSOLE"/>
    </category>
</log4j:configuration>
```

This displays every log in com.foo.* . I want to disable logging in com.foo.bar.* . How do i do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By raising the threhold on the `com.foo.bar` logger:

```
<category name = "com.foo.bar">
   <priority value="WARN"/>
</category>
```

This logger will be used in preference to the `com.foo` one, and has a higher threshold will only lets through WARN or higher.